# Angular 2 ViewChild NgModel Set New Value

Tags: angular

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="referenceNo/LIKE" placeholder="{{'referenceNo' | translate}}" ngModel>
```

```js
@ViewChildren(forwardRef(() => NgModel)) inputs: QueryList<NgModel>;

for (let input of this.inputs.toArray()) {
  //change value input(NgModel Ref)
}
```

Also try to change value from element ref.

```js
@ViewChild(forwardRef(() => NgForm)) form: NgForm;

for (let elRef of this.form.element.nativeElement) {
  elRef.value = "New Value" // Doesnt change value
}
```

Please help i need to manipulate my form inut values, from component class.

Comment: This is so wrong my eyes started hurting.. You want to change the value of the input yes?

Comment: Yes i want to change value from component class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component:

```
public foo: string;

setNewValue(newValue) {
  this.foo = newValue;
}
```

Template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="foo" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'referenceNo' | translate}}">
```

Basically how you would do what you want is to bind a class property (must be `public` if using AOT) to the `ngModel` directive, any changes to the property from the user typing will be reflected in the component since it's "two-way bound" using the `[()]` syntax. For one time bindings you can do `[ngModel]="foo"` but in your scenario you don't want that.

I'd suggest having a read about how `ngModel` works, and also taking a look at Reactive forms using the `FormBuilder`. Which is more powerful and easier to work with when working with forms in general.

Comment: Yes i know this way. So no way to change value my scenario?

Comment: @VolkanOkçu No there isn't. Your "scenario" is not a scenario. It's the wrong way to do it, I don't know how you came up with that in the first place. You don't manipulate DOM attributes directly in Angular, you use things such as ngModel, FormControl, Renderer2 etc. Stepping away from the correct way of doing things will result in a buggy app that doesn't run as intended.

Comment: If i bind every reference ngModel like your example, can i change value with Viewchildren ngmodels? I am doing this abstract super class. I can bind references from implemantation. But i need to change values from super class. Now i need this references from super class so fail again.

Comment: I have 1 more question. Why i cant change element ref value? I can change innerHTML orinnerText but value doesnt change. Thank you for help.

Comment: You'd have to open a new question for that and add the necessary code, it's hard to say. You can't change the value because `ngModel` handles it.